# Why checkNotNull() is not annotated with @Nonnull

Tags: java, guava

I found inconvenient that `checkNotNull()` precondition in guava is not marked with `@Nonull` annotation. Consider following example:

```
State(Set<Model> models, Set<Variation> variations) {
  this.models = checkNotNull(models);
  this.variations = checkNotNull(variations);

  if (this.variations == null) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  this.engine = createEngine();
}
```

So IDE could not found that `variations == null` is always false. Is there any particular reasons why this precondition is not marked with `@Nonull` (even if it's arguments are defined using `@Nullable`).

Comment: I might miss the option to sent a PR for a GitHub wiki page, because I would have written something to that extend myself. But since I cant, can somebody add at least a sentende like "Guava does only use @Nullable internally, so all return types are asumed but not marked with @Nonull" (or similar): https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[We haven't used `@Nonnull` anywhere](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/search?q=@Nonnull), sorry.  Why?  We tried adding more null-checking annotations, and we found that:

- Adding all the other annotations is highly verbose.
- `@Nullable` is all we need for `NullPointerTester`.  Admittedly that's more important to Guava developers than Guava users.
- `@Nullable` appeared to have caught most problems.  I admit it's hard to say how many un-checked-in bugs other annotations would have caught before the user found them.

The verbosity was the main thing.  It gets crazy, especially with subtyping and with parameterized types.  We tried to pick a sweet spot for annotations.  Maybe we'll change it one day.  For the moment, though, that's why things are the way they are.

(If we did do something, I suspect we'd try to make `@Nonnull` the default, using `@CheckForNull` for the exceptions instead.  But I haven't looked into it even enough to make sure I've got the meanings right.)

Comment: Some tools might be smart enough to notice that the package-info is annotated with @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.

Comment: Relevant to this question I think we need @ReturnsAreNonnullByDefault too, right? And I don't know whether that exists.

Comment: We have set all packages to non-null by default for parameters, fields, and methods (return values). For the latter two I had to copy the deprecated annotations from FindBugs. I've been quite happy with the result so far. In a move that will no doubt bite me later, I duplicated `@CheckForNull` into a private `@Nullable` and banned the use of the original because the latter name matches the intention much better, is easier to type, and is more readable.

Answer (score 7):

It would indeed be interesting to annotate its result with `@Nonnull`, since `checkNotNull()` throws a NPE if the reference is `null`, which means it never returns `null`:

```
  @Nonnull
  public static <T> T checkNotNull(T reference) {
    if (reference == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return reference;
  }
```

Note that you'd need to change your code to:

```
if(this.variations == null)
```

since the `@Nonnull` would only apply to the result of `checkNotNull()`, but says nothing about its argument. Note that we cannot annotate the argument with `@Nonnull`, since we might often be checking nullable variables.